# How to restore kivy default configs?

Tags: kivy

Hi guys I messed up with kivy Config object and called Config.write()
so now my app won't even run
I removed the fullscreen option in the graphics section.
(I know I messed up really bad!!!!!)

Comment: just had the same problem thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the file that I Wrote in my local and deleted it
and it worked!
Thank you Fadi Abu Raid for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows the configuration file is under

`C:\Users\user\.kivy\config.ini`

This is my current configuration should be the default because I didn't change it.

```
[kivy]
keyboard_repeat_delay = 300
keyboard_repeat_rate = 30
log_dir = logs
log_enable = 1
log_level = info
log_name = kivy_%y-%m-%d_%_.txt
window_icon = 
keyboard_mode = dock
keyboard_layout = qwerty
desktop = 1
exit_on_escape = 1
pause_on_minimize = 0
kivy_clock = default
default_font = ['Roboto', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf']
log_maxfiles = 100
window_shape = data/images/defaultshape.png
config_version = 21

[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 0
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 800
resizable = True
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0

[input]
mouse = mouse
wm_touch = wm_touch
wm_pen = wm_pen

[postproc]
double_tap_distance = 20
double_tap_time = 250
ignore = []
jitter_distance = 0
jitter_ignore_devices = mouse,mactouch,
retain_distance = 50
retain_time = 0
triple_tap_distance = 20
triple_tap_time = 375

[widgets]
scroll_timeout = 250
scroll_distance = 20
scroll_friction = 1.
scroll_stoptime = 300
scroll_moves = 5

[modules]

[network]
useragent = curl
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I'm using pycharm on mac so this didn't work.